# How to regex match text before a multiple chars including whitespace?

Tags: regex, dart

I working with Dart and need to match text after a keyword `key:` and before either a `,`, `)`, or space  . I also need the text to contain a `.`, so `key: blah.blah,` would match for `blah.blah` but `key: blah,` would not. Below is what I have so far, which is almost working. Problem is it breaks when I add the `\s` for whitespace?

```
final expression = RegExp(r'(?<=key\:)(.*?)(?=[\,|\)|\s])');
```

My follow-up question is I only want to match for letters, numbers, `(` or `.`, so `key: blah@blah.blah,` would not match but `key: blah.blah(0)` would.

Answer (score 0):

For your first request, you should use this expression (be carefully with the space after `:`):

```
(?<=key\: )[^,)\s]*\.[^,)\s]+
```

For your second request, you should use:

```
(?<=key\: )[a-zA-Z\d\.\(\)]+$
```

Well, your requests are some contradictory and they need more context, IMHO.